# How do I check for two words on a string using include()?

Tags: javascript

I've tried &&, ||, and some other comparison methods between the words. Currently, it's like this:

```
if(str.includes("a", "b") {
console.log(a and b received)
}
```

And the problem is that currently, it logs that a and b received even if the string only has a, when I only want it to log that if the string has both a and b. Does anyone know what's the proper command for this? (ps I'm a total noob to js and I have no idea am I even supposed to use include() for something like this)

Comment: Can you provide some examples of how you've tried `&&`, `||` and other comparison methods?

Comment: You can use regex to match the cases with string, in your case, the regex will be `/(a*b)/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if(str.includes("a") && str.includes("b")) {
console.log(a and b received)
}
```

should do it.

Comment: `console.log("a and b received")`

Answer (score 2):

There are various method:

#### Method 1 - using `includes`

```js
 str.includes("a") && str.includes("b")
```

#### Method 2 - using `indexOf`

```js
str.indexOf("a") > -1 && str.indexOf("b") > -1
```

#### Method 3 - using `contains`

```js
str.contains("a") && str.contains("b")
```

#### Method 4 - using `search`

```js
str.search('a') > -1 && str.search('a') > -1
```

#### Method 5 - using `match`

```js
str.match('a') && str.match('b')
```

#### Method 6 - using `RegExp`

```js
RegExp('a').test(str) && RegExp('a').test(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(str.includes("a") && str.includes("b")) {
  console.log("a and b received")
}
```

You can also read from the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes, that `includes` function receives only a `valueToFind` argument (plus an optional `fromIndex` One), and that's the reason why your approach doesn't work.

Comment: `I've tried &&, ||, and some other comparison methods between the words.` in this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(str.includes('word1') && str.includes('word2')){
  console.log("word1 and word2 received");
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer already provided?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, when i started writing this answer, there were no other answers written. By the time I completed and posted, there were two same answers. Just a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A canonical solution is to take a quantifier, like [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and take the result.

The advantage is to have the option to add more values to the array for checking isntead of adding another condition for a check.

```
if (["a", "b"].every(part => str.includes(part)) {
    console.log('str contains a and b');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the docs the [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

Can take up to 2 parameters the second parameter is optional (by default is 0) and indicates de position where is going to start the searching.

**.includes()** method is case sensitive so be aware of that.

```js
let str = "Helloab World";

if ( str.includes("a") && str.includes("b") ){
  console.log( "a and b received" )
} else {
  console.log("String do not containt a or b")
}

// Example with the second parameter.
// Would go to the else statement because it would
// start searching from the 8th position of the string
console.log("Second if statement start here")
if ( str.includes("a", 8) && str.includes("b", 8) ){
  console.log( "a and b received" )
} else {
  console.log("String do not containt a or b")
}
```

Hope this example can help you a little.